# display elements if the last number in their id is smaller than i

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have span elements that are named id="tag1", id="tag2", etc. and I only want to `.show()` the spans with a last number in their id smaller than eg. 19.
These elements belong to a `class="notVis"`, which is `$(".notVis").hide();` when the page is first loaded.

I am entirely new at this and self-teaching, this is why the below attempted code will produce a lot of laughs, I am sure. Thanks for any help!

```
var iMax = 19;
var i = 3;
var field = "tag" + i;
while(i < iMax){
   $("#field").show(); i = i + 1; field = "tag" + i;
}
```

Comment: Why not just assign a second class to those tags?  That way `$('tagsUnder20').show()` will work.  One line, one search.

Comment: Problem is that the var iMax will always be different, according to the php input from the previous page...

Comment: @DanPichelman that's true, but if the number (19 in this case) is itself dynamic, that gets messy.

Comment: Are the elements always in order? Your approach in your loop seems like it's far more expensive that needed. If they're in order, and you provide some markup, an better solution can be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to substitute in the value of "field" in the selector:

```
$("#" + field).show();
```

JavaScript doesn't have any built-in mechanism for interpolating dynamic values into strings, though some other languages do.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var iMax = 19;
var i = 3;
var field;
while(i < iMax){
   field = "tag" + i++;
   $("#" + field).show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I will note that you seem to be making this far more complex than need be, so I'd suggest, instead, the following approach:

```
var iMax = 19;
$('span[id^="field"]').hide().filter(function(i){
    return i < iMax;
}).show();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XWhJG/).

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).